# Sonarqube gitlab report publisher not finishing

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

[image]

I am running sonar-scanner for a repo from gitlab on jenkins. Sonar-scanner upload reports to sonarqube successfully.

The roadmap on jenkins is that: clone repo from gitlab. Start sonar-scanner inside docker container. Sonar-scanner upload reports to sonarqube and open discussion on gitlab commit.

The report file dir size is 13 MB zip size 6MB. I am using proxy for sonarqube. That means my proxy is set correctly(On kubernetes with annotation that is nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size).

My problem is that gitlab issue publisher not finishing for analysis. I tried on a directory that produces 100kb report file size that is successfully open disscussion on gitlab. I think my issue is related with the report size. But couldn't find any solution.

Do you have any?

**Additional infoes:**

Sonarqube version: 7.9.3 (build 33349) CE

Sonar-Scanner: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli: latest(Digest:sha256:135815)

Gitlab Version: GitLab Community Edition 11.9.1

Sonar-gitlab-plugin: https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin (sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonarqube was behind a load balancer. I increased proxy-body-size on both sonarqube and nginx load balancer to 25 mb and t solved. If you face with similar issue look your web server configs.